# Zoom to location when setting a location in nodeapi

Tags: 6, nodes, javascript, location

In some instances I am automatically setting the wkt field on my content type. I am doing this in `hook_nodeapi()` when the `$op` is prepared. This is setting the the wkt fine. The map shows my marker in the correct location on the screen. However it does not zoom in on it (this is set in my preset). `openlayers_render_map()` does not see the change to the `$node` so uses the default settings where I am zoomed out on a world map view. Is there any way that when setting the wkt field programmatically to zoom to the marker? Once the node is saved and I edit it then it does zoom to the marker.

Comment: you are not using a views-built overlay, are you?